# Apex Rest callout for Access token

Tags: rest, http, oauth-2.0, salesforce, apex

I want to generate a simple post call from Apex for the access token. I am new to Apex and Rest so is there someone explain me how to do that?

I have endpointurl, client _secret, client_id, scope, and grant_type is Client_credentials'. 
I tried to run this in Postman and it works fine but not in salesforce.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

request.setEndpoint('https://xxx.xxx.eu/o/oauth2/token');

string mybody='{"client_id":"xxxx","client_secret":"xxxx","grant_type":"client_credentials","scope": "xxx.Rest.everything"}';

request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
// Set the body as a JSON object
request.setBody(mybody);

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

// Parse the JSON response
if (response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
        response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
} else {
    System.debug(response.getBody());
}

´´´´
```

Comment: Have you added remote site?

Comment: Please include error messages

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the remote site? It is the probable reason I believe.

If not, try

1. From Setup, enter Remote Site Settings in the Quick Find box, then
   select Remote Site Settings.
2. Click New Remote Site.
3. Enter a descriptive term for the Remote Site Name.
4. Enter the URL for
   the remote site. Optionally, enter a description of the site.
5. Click Save